# When was the last time Magnus Carlsen lost 2 classical games in a row to the same player besides to Wesley So?

Tags: history, chess-variants, statistics, time-control, chess960

Related questions:

1. [When was the last time Magnus Carlsen lost 3 classical games in a row besides to Wesley So?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41508/when-was-the-last-time-magnus-carlsen-lost-3-classical-games-in-a-row-besides-to)
2. [When was the last time Magnus Carlsen lost 2 classical games in a row to the same player besides to Wesley So?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41519/when-was-the-last-time-magnus-carlsen-lost-2-classical-games-in-a-row-to-the-sam)

---

In the 2023 Tata Steel, Magnus lost 2 classical *chess* games in a row, namely to Anish Giri and Nodirbek Abdusattorov. It's said that the last time this happened was in 2015. But that's for different players.

If you allow chess960 and focus only on the same player:

In the 2019 WFRCC, Wesley So beat Carlsen 3x in a row in [classical](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41499/was-the-2019-wfrcc-classical) world championship games.

**Question**: Besides that, when was the last time this happened: Magnus lost 2 classical (chess or chess960) games in a row to the same player (focusing only on their games only of course)?

- Case 1: Draws counting eg Win-Loss-Draw-Loss-Win means only 1x
- Case 2: Draws not counting eg Win-Loss-Draw-Loss-Win means 2x
- Note: In either case, I don't mind if it's all chess games, all chess960 games or a mix of chess and chess960 games eg for Case 1 Win any-Loss chess960-Draw any-Loss chess-Win any is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This happened recently. First, in December 2022, Magnus Carlsen lost to Fabiano Caruana in the 2022 World Blitz. Then, in January 2023, Magnus Carlsen lost again to Fabiano Caruana in the 85th Tata Steel Masters.
Source:https://www.365chess.com/players/Magnus_Carlsen

Comment: The first game was blitz, and blitz != classical ...

Comment: Ooops. Other than that... Ill fix @Glorfindel